# signal names generated on interface "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device" of Network Manager in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, dbus

i am new to Dbus and i am trying to catch the signal generated when Network Cable is plugged in or plugged out.i am trying with sample code given at "http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/detecting-network-connectivity-using-d-bus"

what signal name i shall use in dbus_message_is_signal() to get the info.Provide any sample code too which can clear my concept.

my code is:

```
enter code here

#include<stdio.h>
#include<dbus/dbus.h>
#include <gdbus.h>

#include<stdbool.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dbus/dbus-glib-bindings.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-glib.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-glib-lowlevel.h>

#define PLATFORM_SERVICE          "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
#define PLATFORM_PATH                    "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager"
#define PLATFORM_CONNECTION_IF    "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"


main()
{

        DBusMessage* msg;
        DBusConnection* conn;
        DBusError err;

        printf("Listening for signals\n");

        // initialise the errors
        dbus_error_init(&err);

         //connect to the bus and check for errors

        conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &err);

        if (dbus_error_is_set(&err))
                {
                fprintf(stderr, "Connection Error (%s)n", err.message);
                dbus_error_free(&err);
                }

        if (NULL == conn)
                {
                printf("Error in connection\n");
                exit(1);
                }
 dbus_bus_add_match(conn, "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'", &err);
        dbus_connection_flush(conn);

        if (dbus_error_is_set(&err))
        {
               fprintf(stderr, "Match Error (%s)n", err.message);
               exit(1);
        }

        printf("Match rule sent\n");


         g_message("Listening to D-BUS signals using a connection filter");

 // loop listening for signals being emmitted
        while (true)
        {
                printf("in while \n");
               // non blocking read of the next available message
              dbus_connection_read_write(conn,0);
               msg = dbus_connection_pop_message(conn);

              // loop again if we haven't read a message
               if (NULL == msg)
               {
                      sleep(1);
                      continue;
               }

                if (dbus_message_is_signal(msg, PLATFORM_CONNECTION_IF,"PropertiesChanged"))
                      printf("Received signal propertyChanged \n");
 if (dbus_message_is_signal(msg, PLATFORM_CONNECTION_IF, "DeviceRemoved"))
                      printf("Received signal %s\n", "Device changed");

  // free the message
               dbus_message_unref(msg);
        }
}
```

i can get property changed signal but how to get other signals.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the NetworkManager spec at http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/spec.html -- it provides you with all of the details of the interface.

Signals that can be of interest to you would be "DeviceAdded" and "DeviceRemoved" to discover when devices come and go (cable plugged and unplugged). You can also dive down to the org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device to get the "PropertiesChanged" signal and grab the "state" property, among others.

Comment: Thanks Piel for your reply,but if i try to check for  DeviceAdded or DeviceRemoved signals,i donot get any response,,,in all the cases,the only signal i can get is "Property Changed".Can you Suggest Some sample Codes or What modification i have to make.

Comment: If the device is not generating a DeviceAdded/DeviceRemoved signal in the NetworkManager when it is plugged/unplugged, then I would iterate the list of devices the NetworkManager is aware of and connect to the properties changed signal for each device, then watch for changes in the "state" attribute.

Comment: I would still suggest that you support the DeviceAdded/DeviceRemoved signals so you can add/remove the attachments to the PropertiesChanged signal for the device(s) you're monitoring. And you're welcome.

Comment: Apparently Gnome site has gone through some restructuring and today the link to developer documentation is: https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager. Also, given the "old" in the hostname, I suppose there should be a "new" site somewhere. I just couldn't find it.